# Should answers that only comment on other answers be deleted?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72583483/6879826) for moderator attention suggesting deletion, and a moderator declined my flag.

The answer states that it is updating the accepted answer "*with a key clarification*," but does not provide any new content. The answer does not make an effort to answer the OP question, but merely provides some misguided discussion about the empty HTML element syntax used in the accepted answer. There is a code snippet prefaced with: "*Thus, I have revised the answer below to comply with this.*" The code snippet has been copied from the accepted answer with one `/` character removed from an empty HTML element. The code snippet is followed with:

> Notice the original answer has `/` in before `>`, which is not needed for `img` elements (see references below). Other than this, his answer is correct on how to make an image clickable, that is, to turn an image into a link.

Leaving questions about the value of this "clarification" aside, it seems clear to me that the answer is not an answer to the OP question, but a comment on the accepted answer. Shouldn't such answers be deleted or at least converted to comments?

Comment: This is hardly _only_ commenting on the answer.  It is also a fully self-contained answer to the question.  You don't need to read the other answer to understand it.  How exactly could we convert that to a comment?  It wouldn't work.

Comment: @RyanM -- What part of the answer is not a comment on the empty HTML element from the accepted answer? OP doesn't use the `< />` style empty elements anyway; that comes directly from the accepted answer. I don't see it answering the question at all except that it copy-pastes the code from the accepted answer. I don't think that it should be converted to a comment either; I think it should be deleted.

Comment: *"What part of the answer is not a comment on the empty HTML element from the accepted answer?"* the part where it gives a complete solution as a code block.  If you're providing a different answer (here, one updated for HTML5), the correct way to do that is to post a separate answer.  A comment is not a good place for providing alternate code, and it would be questionable to edit the existing code block (though adding a new one might be okay, though I could see reviewers rejecting it as too large a change).

Comment: @RyanM -- well, both versions are legal HTML5 (which was old-hat when the original answer was written), but that is not really relevant. The point is that the change is _one_ character. This could easily be a comment, and should be in my opinion. It is at best a _bad_ answer, and I downvoted it; I don't see it adding any value at all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I declined your flag.

The reasoning has been already fleshed out in comments, so I might as well [quote Ryan M](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423826/should-answers-that-only-comment-on-other-answers-be-deleted#comment951505_423826):

> If you're providing a different answer (here, one updated for HTML5), the correct way to do that is to post a separate answer.

If that answer were a **minor** improvement, e.g. fixing a typo, then yes, it might make more sense as an edit, or as a comment to the other answer. This is not the case.

Even though the difference with the existing answer boils down to a single character `/`, in the context of HTML markup that is definitely not in the same league as a typo. It's a notable change: if the user had submitted an edit, it could have been rejected as deviating from the author's intent.

The fact that an HTML5 parser might accept both versions of that code is irrelevant. We don't delete newer answers because of backwards-compatibility.

And irrespective of the technicalities, the answer stands on its own: it includes the full code *that answers the question*, an explanation of what is different and a few useful supporting resources.

It doesn't have to be deleted by a moderator.

Comment: The reason that I felt that this was not really an answer is because it seems to exist solely as a critique of the accepted answer (which it references four times; five if you count the copy-pasted code). But I appreciate your response, even if I disagree.